# C# Decimal Range attribute allow Negative min

Tags: c#

I have this `RangeAttribute` and it won't allow me to post negative numbers for the field it is assigned to.

How can I modify this to allow the `decimal.MinValue` and `decimal.MaxValue` as arguments?

```
[Range(0, 
       float.MaxValue, 
       ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid float Number")]
```

I've tried this but it won't even allow it:

> To validate a property against a range of decimal values you must provide the type of the Decimal structure and two string values that will be converted to decimal values.

```
[Range(typeof(Decimal), 
      decimal.MinValue.ToString(), 
      decimal.MaxValue.ToString(), 
      ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid float Number")]
```

Comment: Its because `ToString` is not a constant so you cant define that on an attribute. You could hard code the values as string constants though.

Comment: Why do you even want a `Range` attribute if you want to allow the full range of `float` values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RangeAttribute has three constructors that take two ints, two doubles, or two strings. None of them take a float.

Try declaring it with two doubles, like this:

```
[Range((double)decimal.MinValue, 
       (double)decimal.MaxValue, 
       ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid decimal Number")]
```

Comment: This limitation of the data annotations library is explain by the creators [here](https://jeffhandley.com/2009-07-09/191).

Answer (score 2):

You can hardcode the actual min/max values of decimal in strings to get what you want:

```
[Range(typeof(decimal), 
       "-79228162514264337593543950335",              
       "79228162514264337593543950335", 
        ErrorMessage = "There's an error")]
```

Although at this point, the validation seems pretty useless

Comment: Won't the commas mess this up?

Comment: @DavidG yep they did.  It works with the commas removed

Answer (score -1):

and this doesnt work?

```
[Range(float.MaxValue, 
       float.MaxValue, 
       ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid float Number")]
```

this allows any number

or

```
[Range(-42, 
       +42, 
       ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid float Number")]
```

which allows any number between -42 and + 42

Comment: If it worked, this would only let you ever use a single value :)

Comment: i mean he sasid he could enter a negative value, thats becasue he set the lower bound to zero